# How to put a boarder around div and text on top left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 for some of my web pages. One thing I haven't been able to figure out is how do I put a border around a particular div and show a text in left hand corner?

[Something like this (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFdEf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not bootstrap specific. The example you have pointed to is not an example of styles built-in to boostrap so you will have to customise your code to achieve the same affect.

The closest you can get with the default bootstrap component is a panel, see this link:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: I think I found what I was looking at -- http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html

Comment: @user1223747 that does indeed look like what you are trying to achieve.